# Issue in adding dependencies from local Repository into Apache Livy Interpreter for Zeppelin

Tags: apache-zeppelin, livy

How to add dependencies to the Apache Livy Interpreter in Apache Zeppelin?

I tried adding the way, I did for standard Spark Interpreter inside Zeppelin, it did not work

I tried adding it on livy.spark.jars.packages, it did not work.

All these dependencies are available in my local repositoty

Answer (score 0):

Hope [this](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/interpreter/livy.html#adding-external-libraries) works for you, and for adding local dependencies you can follow the instructions given [here](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0-SNAPSHOT/usage/interpreter/dependency_management.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response, it is able to fetch libs from Maven but not from my local repository, the local repo  is also added in Zeppelin. However, I do not get any issue with standard Spark Interpreter, which is part of Zeppelin. I am using Zeppelin-0.8.0-snapshot version.

Comment: Does Apche Livy team trying to resolve the issue of loading dependency from local repositories?